# Member is inaccessible from Template class object in parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class which has a function that takes in a template List object as a parameter. Using this List object i'm supposed to:

```
//receives a List of NVPair objects and sets the data value in a data member
//of an object in the list according to the corresponding name in the name - value pair
```

Here is my class and function:

```
class Cartoon : public Object {

    string type;
    string name;
    string likes;

public:

    void set(const List<NVPair<string, string>, 10>&& list) {

        //set to this
        list.objArray[0] 
    }

};
```

Here is the List template class:

```
template<typename T, int MAX>
class List {

    T objArray[MAX];
    int index;

public:

    List() : index(0) {}

    size_t size() const {

        return index;
    }

    const T& operator[](int i) const {

        //try {} shit
        return i <= MAX && i >= 0 ? i : -1;
    }

    void operator+=(const T& t) {

        objArray[index++] += t;
    }

    void operator+=(T&& t) {

        objArray[index++] += move(*t);
    }

};
```

Why can't I access the member objArray? It says the member is inaccessible.

The first template argument is of NVPair, another class template. It is:

```
template<typename N, typename V>
class NVPair {

    N name;
    V value;

public:

    NVPair() :name(""), value("") {}
    NVPair(N n, V v) : name(n), value(v) {}
    N name() const { return name; }
    V value() const { return value; }

};
```

I tried setting the data members to protected instead of private but this changes nothing. I also tried setting the

```
void set(const List<NVPair<string, string>, 10> && list)
```

as a pointer type, one reference, no reference or pointer but nothing changes. The member is inaccessible. I think my parameter is wrong but I'm not sure what is wrong with it.

Also the Object class that Cartoon derives off of:

```
class Object {

public:

    virtual void set() = 0;
    virtual const std::string getDSV(char c = VALUE_DELMINITER) const = 0;

};
```

Here is the code that calls the set function

```
auto list = new List <T, OBJECTS_PER_JSON_FILE>();
auto members = new List <NVPair <std::string, std::string>, DATA_MEMBERS_PER_OBJECT>();

//inside a switch loop
case OBJECT_CLOSE:
obj.set(*members);
(*list) += obj;
delete members;
members = nullptr;
break;
```

Comment: Can you (a) post a [**real MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and (b) kindly explain what `NVPair` is doing with what appears to be a series of **constructors** called `name(...)` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig that was a mistake on my part...I meant to call those NVPair not "name" as constructors. I will update my post with the function that calls the .set method

Comment: As long as your updating it, an MCVE would seriously be warranted. Ex: you can't have members and getters with the *same name* (convenient example, `name` and `name()`). Please, *please*, post *real* code.

Comment: @WhozCraig I added the code which calls the set method, it is literally the only place in the code that calls it

Answer (score 1):

> I tried setting the data members to protected instead of private but
>   this changes nothing

That is because you access `list` in Cartoon::set which is completely unrelated (in terms of inheritance) to your list. Hence you cannot access private or protected members from `list`.

Comment: Even though im passing in a List type through a parameter in my Cartoon class? I need to be able to read the data that List contains

Comment: It might be a good idea to strip your code off everything that is not related to your problem in order to get to the core of the problem. That means throw away templates or base classes. In your case it is just about accessing a non-public member of an unrelated class. You could use a public getter() method or declare the caller a friend class to your list class.